# Creating Calculated table using DAX

Tags: dax

I am trying to create a new Table using DAX. This new table will have rows filtered from an existing table called `Table_A`. `Table_A` needs to be filtered based on a column called `PROD_ID` from a related table called `Table_B`. `PROD_ID` column needs to be filtered based on multiple values of Product ids.

This is what I am doing-

```
Subtable_X =
CALCULATETABLE ( TABLE_A, RELATED ( TABLE_B[PROD_ID] ) = OR ( 123, 456, 678, ... ) )
```

The code is obviously not correct. Can anyone help me with a solution to get me the desired result?

Comment: Can you give some minimal example tables for input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Look for DAX [OR](https://dax.guide/op/or/) operator or IN operator:

https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/

This will work:

```
Subtable_X =
CALCULATETABLE ( TABLE_A, RELATED ( TABLE_B[PROD_ID] ) = { 123, 456, 678 } )
```

Alternatively use `||` (double pipes):